# How hide and prevent showing web page content during page load and show an animated gif image instead

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, preload

I designed the site below for my friend: http://noorjamali.info/

How can I prevent showing web site content during web page load? (it has a bad view during page load).

**1**- Would you please introduce me a jquery plugin for this purpose.  As you will see on that web site I act like this:

**css**

```
.Home_Page
{
    display: none;
}
```

**jquery**

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j('.Home_Page').fadeIn(2000);
});
```

but content still  appear during page load.

**2**- How can I fix this issue?
**3**- How can I show an animated gif instead of showing content during page load?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use an inline style,

```
<body style="display:none">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a div with class pageload or something.
Give this div the styles:

```
.pageLoad{
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 1337; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background: #FFF url(loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
}
```

when a page is finished loading, then you hide this div

```
$(window).load(function(){$(".pageLoad").fadeOut(2000);});
```

Comment: nice way, but i am a little worry about height: 100%;

Comment: @SilverLight - I've edited it to use `bottom:0; right:0;` instead of using explicit width and height.

Answer (score 1):

Try There is a new version of QueryLoader 
http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/

Answer (score 1):

Put all your control inside UpdatePanel and create a trigger for the update panel.

Don't load any data/control on Page_Load or any other page event , instead create a function to load data/control on page.

Let the page render empty. Write a javascript on client side pageload event and call the update panel trigger in that javascript. Write the data/control load code on the trigger click at server side. There are some more changes see the example code.

example code (aspx):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upD" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph" EnableViewState="False" runat="server">
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnIsPostBack" Value="0" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnLoadData" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="upr" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upD" DisplayAfter="50">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div id="Layer1" class="busy">
            <img alt="Loading Data" src="<%=PathPrefix %>/Images/loading.gif" /><br />
            Loading...
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

  var flag = false;
    function pageLoad() {
      if (!flag) {
        document.getElementById('m_c_btnLoadData').click();
        flag = true;
      }
    }

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
    var postBackElement;
    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
        $get('m_c_upr').style.display = 'block';
    }
    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
        $get('m_c_upr').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this website..

This actually shows the page even when the loading is not complete. What you can do is create two DIV's. One that contains the main page and the other that contains the image that is shown while yer getting prepared.

You can do this using the jquery hide and show..